# VoiceOver and Emoji and Symbols viewer

Tags: macos, emoji, voiceover

VoiceOver uses Control-Command-Space for launching an action but I can't use it because Emoji and Symbols Viewer hijacks it. Is there a way how to disable Emoji and Symbols viewer?

I need VoiceOver more than emojis.

Comment: VoiceOver does not use ctrl + cmd + space. The keyboard command you need to use is ctrl + opt + space or capslock + space if you set capslock to be a voiceOver modifier in VoiceOver Utility > general.

Comment: It used to but was changed

Answer (score 1):

You can assign a different keyboard shortcut to the Emoji & Symbols menu item.

I usually add/remove a <kbd>cmd</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>alt</kbd> or <kbd>shift</kbd> modifier when remapping menu items like this.

*System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > App Shortcuts > + (plus button)*
[image]